# redis with nodejs+socketio and python, message event fired twice?

Tags: python, events, redis, socket.io, message

I've set a nodejs server along with simple python script with redis-py.

I have this on my nodejs server:

```
var http = require('http');
var server=http.createServer(onRequest).listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var fs= require('fs');
var sub = redis.createClient();
sub.subscribe('channel');


function onRequest(req,res){
    var index;
    fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
        index = data;
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
        res.write(index);
        res.end();
    });

};

var sockets=[];
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  sockets.push(socket);
  console.log(sockets.length);
  sub.on('message', function(channel, message){
    console.log(message);
    sockets[0].emit('chat message',message);
    });

  io.emit('chat message', "enter nickname");
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});
```

This is just a simple test where I've tried to find out why my messages are sent multiple times.

I've figured that `sub.on('message')` is fired twice for each message that I send from python. Why?

The python code is pretty simple:

```
import redis
r=redis.StrictRedis()
pubsub=r.pubsub()
r.publish('channel',"HHHHHHH")
```